# Usage of rather

Tags: adverbs

In the following two sentences which one is correct regarding the usage of **rather**

> Men are rather impressed by beauty then by character.

> Men are impressed rather by beauty then by character.

I think the first one is correct. But in my book second one is correct, I don't understand how?

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, it’s “than”, not “then”.

As Kate Bunting mentions, the second example is valid, though rather old-fashioned and formal.

The first sort of sounds like it’s trying to say:

> Men are rather impressed by beauty.

“Rather” here just means “very”.

One acceptable and common way to phrase what you're trying to say would be:

> Men are impressed by beauty rather than (by) character.

Also note that the second “by”, which I’ve bracketed, is optional.

Comment: I would say that _rather by beauty than by character_ is perfectly valid, just rather old-fashioned and formal.

Comment: @KateBunting That’s true, I’ll update my answer to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Chris's answer...

Even better to avoid using 'rather' here. So:

> Men are impressed by beauty in a woman, not character

or

> Men are more impressed by a woman's beauty than her character.

Answer (score 0):

> Men are rather impressed by beauty than character.

Will rather be the right answer to your question.

Here `rather` is giving more emphasis on one over the other.